# NMOS IV characteristics turned out to be different with same configuration

Tags: nmos

I am ploting the IV characteristics of the NMOS.

Here I sweep the Vgate and the VDS.

note that the Vdc=-Vg has a minus sign, so Vg is actually positive.

The only difference between the 2 setup is that in one I put the positive drain voltage at the top. The other one I put the positive drain voltage at the bottom.

But why I am getting 2 different IV characteristic results? should't they be the same?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]